# Open File method in Perl

Tags: perl, file-io, methods

I tested `>>` and `>` for Open destination file in my code below, it work well. What's the different for them?

```
my $sourfile = "ch1.txt";
my $destfile = "chapter1.txt";

open (SOURFILE, $sourfile);
open (DESTFILE, ">>$destfile"); #both >> and > work here.

#my $fh = \*DATA;  
my $fh = \*SOURFILE;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference:

```
>    Open file for writing.
>>   Open file for appending.
```

You might want to switch to using the 3-argument form of [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), and to using lexical variables as file handles:

```
open(my $handle, '>', "some_file") or die $!;
```

Comment: The 3-argument is a very good idea. As is using lexical filehandles. But they are completely separate features. You don't need to be using 3-argument open in order to use lexical filehandles.

Answer (score 3):

Apologies in advance for being terse, but [open - perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html). In fact, I would generalise my answer to: always try http://perldoc.perl.org first. Forums/Q&A sites are your *last* resort, not your *first*.

Answer (score 1):

`>` creates, or truncates if it already exists.  `>>` creates, or appends to an existing file.  (And it's not a method; Perl 5 isn't really all that OO unless you squint.)